# How to lift the Frobenius map on $W(k)[[t]]$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $k$ be a perfect field of characteristic $p$ with ring of Witt vectors $W(k)$.

Define the Frobenius endomorphism $F(t)=t^p$ on $W(k)/pW(k)$.

Now define the ring $W(k)[[t]]$ be extending the ring $W(k)$.

> How to lift the Frobenius $F$ to the map $F(t)=t^p+p^2t$ on the ring $W(k)[[t]]$ ?

> Is the lift again a Frobenius map ?

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-derivation) is a concept of $p$-derivation. If $\delta_p$ be the $p$-derivation map on $W(k)$ then the lift of the Frobenius $F(t)=t^p$ $\left(\text{mod} \  pW(k) \right) $ is given by $$F(t):=t^p+p \delta(t).$$
This is bijective if $W(k)$ is $p$-torsion free.

Any hints please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remark: the Frobenius on $W(k)$ is not given by $F(w) = w^p.$ Since $p\neq 0$ in $W(k)$, this won't be a ring morphism!

To check if your map $F : W(k)[\![t]\!]\to W(k)[\![t]\!]$ is a lift of Frobenius, where $F$ is the  Frobenius on $W(k)$ and $F(t) = t^p + p^2t,$ you need to check if it is the Frobenius modulo $p.$ However, this is clear: $F(t)\equiv t^p\pmod{p},$ and you already know that the Frobenius lift on $W(k)$ satisfies the desired property.

Comment: I should have said $F(t)=t^p$ in $W(k)/pW(k)$ is a Frobenius.Thanks for nice answer